# How does this 2D DCT code actually work?

Tags: c, dct

Here is the code:

```
void dct(const tga_image *tga, double data[8][8],
    const int xpos, const int ypos)
{
    int i,j;
    double in[8], out[8], rows[8][8];

    /* transform rows */
    for (j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        for (i=0; i<8; i++)
            in[i] = (double) pixel(tga, xpos+i, ypos+j);
        dct_1d(in, out, 8);
        for (i=0; i<8; i++) rows[j][i] = out[i];
    }

    /* transform columns */
    for (j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        for (i=0; i<8; i++)
            in[i] = rows[i][j];
        dct_1d(in, out, 8);
        for (i=0; i<8; i++) data[i][j] = out[i];
    }
}
```

It is taken from listing2.c found at https://unix4lyfe.org/dct/

I have just 1 question, we fill in rows as rows[j][i] but then read it out rows[i][j]. As per the 2D DCT formula we transpose the DCT matrix and not the actual data. Why is the actual data being transposed?

Comment: I add that this is HIGHLY inefficient code if you have to do a lot of DCTs.

Comment: yes, as far as I know the some fast DCT algorithm would be used in practice, however if doing DCT in hardware like in FPGA, this method may be just fine

Comment: what would you personally recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume `xpos` as horizontal index and `ypos` as vertical index, then the following is true.

The function `dct_1d(*,*,*);` works on only *1-d arrays* (here `in` and `out`). What you are getting carried away by is due to the `indexing` jugglery for *2d arrays* in *C* here (in particular `rows` here).

By a simple swap of variables `i` and `j` in the first `for` block, the same code can be rewritten as follows which will make physical sense as you are trying (see the comments):

```
void dct(const tga_image *tga, double data[8][8],
    const int xpos, const int ypos)
{
    int i,j; /* as in matrix[i][j] */
    double in[8], out[8], rows[8][8];

    /* transform rows (each is running horizontally with j) */
    for (i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<8; j++)
            in[j] = (double) pixel(tga, xpos+j, ypos+i); /* fill current row i */
        /* Note above xpos in an image is horizontal as j is in a matrix[i][j] in c and
        vice versa. (The fallacy that you will make is the following: You will think that 
        xpos corresponds to i and ypos corresponds to j, which is incorrect.) */
        dct_1d(in, out, 8); /* transform current row i */
        for (j=0; j<8; j++) rows[i][j] = out[j]; /* copy back current row i */
    }

    /* transform columns  (each is running vertically with i) */
    for (j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        for (i=0; i<8; i++)
            in[i] = rows[i][j]; /* fill current column j */
        dct_1d(in, out, 8); /* transform current column j */
        for (i=0; i<8; i++) data[i][j] = out[i]; /* copy back current column j */
    }
}
```